# Need to Capture whatever the data after multiple dots

Tags: regex

I'm relatively new to regex, now I am facing an issue to extract the data `"VAL................................ Deal value ($ Mil)"` after multiple dots. I have tried doing it `".*?\W+\s+"` with this expression but it stops at $ and I need all the data after dots  like " Deal value ($ Mil)".

Does anyone know what I did wrong here? Also could someone please recommend a good resource for learning regex?

Comment: You can use this tool to test your regex, and learn how your regex works: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What is the code you used to run your regex?

Comment: posted a solution which uses tr command to achieve the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this regular expression "(?<=.|^)[^.]+$" to capture "VAL................................ Deal value ($ Mil)" only

Deal value ($ Mil)

this part after the dots.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this which doesn't use regex.

stack.txt

```
"VAL................................ Deal value ($ Mil)"
```

using tr

```
less stack.txt | tr -d '"VAL.'
```

output

```
 Deal value ($ Mil)
```